# How to extract string between two slashes php

Tags: php

i know that its easy to extract string between two slashes using explode() function in php, What if the string is like

**localhost/used_cars/search/mk_honda/md_city/mk_toyota**

i want to extract string after mk_ and till the slashes like:** honda,toyota **

any help would be highly appreciated.

I am doing like this

```
echo strpos(uri_string(),'mk') !== false ? $arr = explode("/", $string, 2);$first = $arr[0]; : '';
```

but not working because if user enter mk_honda in any position then explode() is failed to handle that.

Comment: Explode and do a foreach on exploded items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regex:

http://ideone.com/DNHXsf

```
<?php

$input = 'localhost/used_cars/search/mk_honda/md_city/mk_toyota';

preg_match_all('#/mk_([^/]*)#', $input, $matches);

print_r($matches[1]);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => honda
    [1] => toyota
)
```

Comment: Daniel ! Why its not getting **toyota** as mk_ ??

Comment: @VehicleCorner Because I had to jump to work. But I was close. Next time, consider accepting the least complex solution ;-)

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Alder ! Your solution is efficient and straight forward....  because it leads to the solution. i  have ended with this                                                                            `preg_match_all('#mk_([^/]*)#')`

Answer (score 1):

Explode your string by `/`, then check every element of array with `strpos`:

```
$string = 'localhost/used_cars/search/mk_honda/md_city/mk_toyota';
$parts = explode('/', $string);
$r = [];
foreach ($parts as $p) {
    // use `===` as you need `mk_` in position 0
    if (strpos($p, 'mk_') === 0) {   
        // 3 is a length of `mk_`
        $r[] = substr($p, 3);    
    }
}
echo'<pre>',print_r($r),'</pre>';
```

Comment: Thank you very much  **U_mulder**

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

```
$str='localhost/used_cars/search/mk_honda/md_city/mk_toyota';
$str=explode('/',$str);
$final=[];
foreach ($str as $words){
(!empty(explode('_',$words)))?(isset(explode('_',$words)[1]))?$final[]=explode('_',$words)[1]:false:false;
}
$final=implode(',',$final);
echo $final;
```

It give output as

> cars,honda,city,toyota